# Get rotate angle to move a robot in 3D environment

Tags: ros, uav, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an UAV and my idea is to make it moves around some points I pass to it.
My logic is the following:
1- Moves UAV in z-axis to adjust high;
2- Rotates around z-axis;
3- Moves forward on x-axis until reach the goal.

Step 1 works fine, but I'm getting problems on step number 2.
I have one coordinate frame for the the UAV and  I get the angle between the uav and the point (in the world) as a transform between the frames of my `goal_point` and the  `UAV`:

```
angle = transform_goal_robotPose.getRotation().getAngle();
```

However, I cannot get a metric to compare with and establish that the uav has rotated the correct angle and then can go to step 3.
I was thinking about something like a comparison `if (angle == expected_angle)`, but couldn't figure out none.
Someone knows how can I get it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285914/get-rotate-angle-to-move-a-robot-in-3d-environment/) by [bxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30323/bxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the [look_at_pose](http://wiki.ros.org/look_at_pose) package. It will do that calculation for you.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2018-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0